# How can I remove git connection permanently in VS 2019?

Tags: visual-studio

I had connected team from my home mistakely and now the project seems to be connected team in VS 2019 . How can I completely remove Git connection?

I clicked team solution but in there when I right click, remove option is disabled. How can I achieve these? VS documents are weird as you know. They  never support and finds way to make  something most difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the hidden .git folder. It should remove it from Visual Studio.

Comment: It works ! Thank you. But VS must serve option to handle this from VS itself. We should not have to be deal with this manual operation.

Comment: Unfortunately, they still don't have an option to do that via their IDE, only via this workaround :\